# Jsbin dark theme

Tags: themes, jsbin

So in order to change Jsbin's theme one can go to console and write

```
jsbin.settings.editor.theme = "theme-you-want";
```

as I read [here](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/09/custom-jsbin-code-editor-settings.html).

I like monokai theme but unfortunately there is a big drawback about dark themes. When you get your cursor on a line, whole line turnes white (like marking the whole line). The problem is that text is also white and I can't see text! Does anyone else have this problem and a possible workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Console of the Browser and put this...

```
jsbin.settings.editor.styleActiveLine=false
```

...and then refresh the page.  That will turn off the styling for the active line.

Or, if you want it to be highlighted and are cool with playing with the UserStyle sheet of your browser you can add this....

```
.focus div.CodeMirror-activeline-background {
  background-color: #eee !important;
}
.focus div.CodeMirror-activeline .CodeMirror-linenumber {
  background-color: #ccc !important;
  color: #2c3dad !important;
}
```

...and adjust the colours to your liking.

If your on windows and use Chrome you can use my tool to get to the style sheet easily...
http://forum.valorsolo.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=269&hilit=extension+opener
...one cool thing about the userstyle sheet in Chrome is the page will update as soon as you save the file.